# Trying to Load and Save objects in C# / JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, save, load

Section giving difficulties

```
const string _studentRepositoryPath = @"students.json"; 

        static void Save() {
            using (var file = File.CreateText(_studentRepositoryPath))
        {
            file.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(studentsList));
        }
        }
            static List<Student> Read() {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Student>>(File.ReadAllText(_studentRepositoryPath));
        }
        static List<Student> studentsList =  new List<Student>();
```

Trying to get the Data to Save into a JSON file so when the program is reopened students can be search.

Issue: JSON file updates after creating a student object but when exiting and reopening the program it says students do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `await` it

```
public static async Task Save() 
{
    using (var file = File.CreateText(_studentRepositoryPath))
    {
        await file.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(studentsList));
    }
}
```

or just use [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8)